# Remote Desktop resolution fail

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, resolution, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a notebook with WIN10 and my screen resolution is 1920x1080.
I connect in RDP with a PC of our customer. It is a virual server with Windows Server 2012 R2.
When i connect i see a big toolbar, big desktop icon while the windows and other software such as Excel has the right dimension. Our software (based on java) has a very very small font instead.

If i change my laptop settings chancing text dimension from 100% to 175% i have my desktop bigger and when i connect with the customer his icons are even more bigger while our software is quite normal.

In RDP I can't change screen setting of the client, what can i do to solve the issue?
PS: I attach a photo hope it helps
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSu6f.jpg)

Comment: Can't you change "Remote desktop size" to agree with the remote resolution in the RDP connection dialog?

Comment: No i can't. In RDP you can't change this kind of settings

Comment: Sure you can, in the Display tab.

Comment: "The display setting can't be changed from a remote session". This is the message I have in all Display tabs. And all the cursors and bar ghosted of course

Comment: This is to be done before connecting.